# NLog - Extending Nlog - callsite - dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am trying to use NLog to log some things in our system. This is a very complicated system, multi-threading with message queues in different places.

We needed to extend NLog to log some other items that way we needed. 
After extending NLog, we found the callsite info was wrong. Some searching on Stack gave me a solution. 
My concern now is, with the extending we have done (passing the TypeName) we could have several hundred log instances, and I have a bad feeling that this will get backed up really fast.

I don't see a dispose method for NLog, so I don't know how garbage collection will pick this up.

If I have 100 classes, each running on different threads processing 1000 transactions a second, and each of these is logging and creating a new log instance, I see problems in my future.

I am open for suggestions. Please let me know if this will even be a problem, and if so, possible solutions?

EDIT: Adding code: - Here is the ExtenderClass (takes the class name)

```
private readonly Logger _logger;

        public NLogLogger(Type t)
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(t.FullName);
        }
        public void Trace(string message, string systemUserID, string transactionID, string description)
        {
             if (_logger.IsTraceEnabled)
                {
                     Write(LogLevel.Trace, message, systemUserID, transactionID, description);
                }
        }
```

Here is a class that uses it: - This class will be instantiated for each thread task, so maybe 500 on a busy day.

```
public class ThreadTask : TaskBase
    {
        private readonly NLogLogger _logger = new NLogLogger(typeof(ThreadTask));    
        public Method(string val)
           {
               _logger.Trace(message);
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern for creating your logger instances with NLog (and with log4net for that matter) is to do something like this in each class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    logger.Debug("Hello from inside DoSomething");
  }
}
```

This way, there is only one logger instance instantiated per class (that has a logger created as above).  So, there should not be an issue of an excessive number of loggers being created simply because a lot of class instances are created.  Also, since the typical pattern is to use static logger instances, the loggers will remain in effect throughout the life of the application (or maybe AppDomain), so no Dispose is needed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I am extending nLog, so I have a base class. I have to pass the type to the base class for the callsite to be correct.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are having.  Why are you going to have several hundred log instances?  By declaring your logger similar to the way I illustrate above (takinging into account the fact that you have subclassed the logger), you should have one logger instance per class in your application.  So, if you have 1 class (that has a logger as a static member) and you create 100 instances of the class, you will have only 1 instance of the logger.  Can you post some code showing how you declare and create the logger within your classes?